# Awk split big file conditionally in multiple output files

Tags: awk

I have to split a 90 GB file into multiple files conditionally (the file is a multiple-table file to split by single table).

I have created a solution in ksh and awk that cycles on the table rules and with awk selects whether to print in the output file or not. The problem is that for 29 rules I have to read the source file (90 GB) 29 times.

Is it possible to write on multiple files with a single read of the source file, redirecting in one or another output conditionally?

Comment: Just a wild guess ... http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils#csplit-invocation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html) (it is specified by POSIX, so should be available with other awks). A simple example:

```
$ awk '$1 % 2 {print > "odd"; next} {print > "even"}' <(seq 1 10)
$ tail -n +1 odd even                                            
==> odd <==
1
3
5
7
9

==> even <==
2
4
6
8
10
```

So, you could create an array with 29 filenames, or construct them using variables (`print > "filenum" n`, `n` being some counter), or ...

Comment: Many thanks. I can edit the  rule file with redirection (silly me for not thinking something so easy). This way i can read the file only 1 time.